# Limits of integration $\iint_A \mathrm{d}A$ over a bounded area of $\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

I am interested in correctly determining the limits of the area integral $\iint_A \mathrm{d}A$ for the following surface area $A$ enclosed by $y = 0.5x + 2, \; y = x^2 -1, \; y = -2x + 2$ (they go as $y_1, y_2, y_3$) :

[image]

The line $y_1$ meets the curve $y_2$ at $(2,3)$.

Regarding the limits, I believe that they should be :

$$\iint_A \mathrm{d}A = \int_0^1 \int_{-2x + 2}^{0.5x + 2} \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x+ \int_1^2 \int_{x^2-1}^3 \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x$$

If I am mistaken, please correct me or guide me to the proper limits.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first double integral is fine. In the second one, in the integral with respect to $y$ the limits should be $x^2-1$ and $0.5x+2$.

Comment: I was afraid that such an integral will result in the "area" underneath them. What would be a good trick to always be sure about my limits ?

Comment: @Rebellos If you are integrating $dy dx$, for each $x_0$ you draw the vertical line $x=x_0$ and find where it lies inside the region. In this example you have a transition at $x=1$, from the two lines being your bounds to the parabola becoming the lower bound (but the upper line is still the upper bound).